# Op-amp high-pass filter and low open-loop gain at higher frequencies

Tags: analog, filter, gain, high-pass-filter, 741-opamp

How can a high-pass filter work when the open-loop gain of an op-amp completely attenuates from a certain frequency?

I understand that the open-loop gain of an op-amp is what limits every closed-loop gain. So if a high-pass filter is a closed-loop gain, how does a high-pass filter still work (at high frequencies)?

[image]

Comment: Gabriel9721 - Hi, Please remember the [site rule](/help/referencing) which requires that when a post includes content (e.g. text, image, photo etc.) copied or adapted from elsewhere, that original content must be correctly referenced. The source webpage or PDF etc. should be linked as a minimum (references for books / articles should include title, author(s), publisher, edition, page numbers etc.). Please can you edit your answer to include the required source link for the original image? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very true! All op-amp high pass filters are stopped by the open loop gain curve. They are actually band pass filters.

In actual applications, the "high-pass" bandwidth is does not need to be unlimited. In fact restricting the higher frequencies reduces noise and so is desireable.

So the trick is to trade gain for bandwidth. The gain-bandwidth product GBW is reported in op-amp datasheets.

> How can a HPF work

The HP cutoff is the most important. Then you must choose the amplifier and closed loop gain to deliver the important frequencies in the application.

Answer (score 0):

> How can a high-pass filter work when the open-loop gain of an op-amp completely attenuates from a certain frequency?

It doesn't work. The moment you employ an op-amp with limited bandwidth, the system is constrained to pass only frequencies up to the point where the op-amp begins attenuating. At that point output amplitude falls again, and your expected "high-pass" behaviour is lost.

Consequently, the system is only able to pass frequencies unattenuated *between* the lower cut-off frequency defined by the high-pass elements, and the upper cut-off frequency imposed by the op-amp.

Theoretically, if you were to use an ideal op-amp, under ideal conditions, a high-pass configuration would not suffer this attenuation at high frequency, which is why we still call it "high-pass".

In practice, though, op-amps are not ideal, and there are always parasitic capacitances and inductances present, so upper frequency is always bounded. All systems in reality are "low-pass" or "band-pass".

I'm not sure how to bring "closed-loop" or "open-loop" into this argument, except to say that the op-amp doesn't change its behaviour just because the loop is closed. The entire system's behaviour maybe be different with the loop closed, but the op-amp still considers itself to be independent, and it still operates exactly as it would with the loop open.

In other words, closing the loop doesn't change anything about the op-amp itself, and its foibles are still present, including limited bandwidth, and it still has the same gain (hundreds of thousands or millions). You don't make the op-amp suddenly better at high frequency by closing the loop. You don't change its gain by closing the loop. You only change the *overall system behaviour*, but that behaviour is still constrained by the op-amp's own limiations.

That said, there are ways to overcome certain op-amp limitations, but that's another topic altogether.